# Kinemaster on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: video-editor

I have **Ubuntu 16.04** on *Dell Vostro 15*. I want to install kinemaster on my pc. Can somebody suggest a fast and easy way ? I know it can be installed on **Andriod**, but can it be installed on an Ubuntu (linux) pc. If yes, please suggest a way

Comment: Not at this time it cannot be installed.  The company has only made mobile platform versions of it.  Maybe ask them to make a desktop version of it:  https://kinemastercorp.com/contact-us-en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can directly. But you can try using an Android emulator then add the program to it or optionally use one of the many different Ubuntu friendly video editors.

Looking up the Dell Vostro 15, there are several versions. The 4 numbers that follow (15) will help others provide better answers.